# How do I stop canvas reacting to mouse when obscured by a 3D object

Tags: canvas, unity-game-engine

I have my canvas in world space. I have a 3D cube partially obscuring a button on the canvas, but I am still able to operate the button by clicking on the cube.

Can I tell Unity not to let its UI react to parts that are covered by 3D game objects?

Comment: Few question....How are you detecting the `Button` click on the UI?  Also do you have any code that detects click on the Cube? If yes, please tell us how you are detecting clicks on the cube. You edit your question and add that information. This is required to see how to fix your current problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the respective canvas under `Graphic Raycaster` there is the point `Blocking Objects`. You can use this to have objects block the ui (either `2D` or `3D` or `All`). From my quick testing that should do what you want if you used this for your ui.